# What is the difference between these two Deployment Targets?

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, project, deployment-target

What is the difference between these two Deployment Targets?

[image: Deployment Target In Blue-Project-Icon Tab]

[image: Deployment Target In No-Project-Icon Tab]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881048/what-is-the-difference-between-target-and-project

Comment: In addition to the answers (or references), note that if you do not want them to be different, you can have the target inherit the value from the project. Go to the target's _Build Settings_ tab, select _iOS Deployment Target_ line and hit backspace. If you switch back to the _General_ tab, you will notice that _Deployment Info: Deployment Target_ will now show the project-set value (in grey). Selecting any value will re-introduce the line you removed in the _Build Settings_ tab.

Answer (score 2):

There are project level and specific target level.
Each project had one project target and more specific target. Each project-level build setting applies to all targets in the project unless explicitly overridden by the build settings for a specific target.

In top picture it's project target and it's setting will be inherited by specific target.

In bottom it's specific target, each change will only affect to this target. Not affect to another specific target or project target. You can add specific target much as you want, if not setting anything there's setting will inherit from project target.

read more about build setting [Build_Settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Build_Settings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009328-CH6-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

A target inherits the project build settings, but you can override any of the project settings by specifying different settings at the target level. There can be only one active target at a time; the Xcode scheme specifies the active target.

For further information you can read the documentation
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html